# Import modules that don't exist (yet)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wish to create my own variation of `amoffat's`[`sh`](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) module, where it can import pretty much any command from user's UNIX path, such as:

```py
from sh import hg
```

However, I am having a hard time finding a way to intercept / override python's own `import [...]` and `from [...] import [...]`. At this point I simply need a way to at least get [the name of] the object of the `from` import, at which point I can simply `setattr()` and `partial()` my way from there, I hope. I'm at a complete loss of how to do this at the moment, however, and hence, have no code to show for it. 
     The gist of what I'm going for:

```py
from test import t # Even though "t" doesn't exist in the module (yet)
```

Any help with the full code would be greatly appreciated!

---

## Final Answer, consolidated:

```py
def __getattr__(name):
    if name == '__path__': raise AttributeError
    print(name)
```

Comment: download amoffat's [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) module and see source code.

Comment: Seem a bit too convoluted for me to understand at the moment; I need a _much_ simpler example.

Comment: maybe there is no simpler way.

Comment: How about [this specific class](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/858adf0c682af4c40e41f34d6926696b7a5d3b12/sh.py#L3328)?

Comment: It _still_ seems too complicated; I may have to read up more on `__getattr__`, but thanks for the [perma]link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a straightforward way *if you are on Python 3.7+*, [PEP-562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/), which allows you to define `__getattr__` at the module level:

```
def __getattr__(name):
    if name == "t":
        return "magic"
    raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__!r} has no attribute {name!r}")
```

There is also a function `__dir__` that you can define to declare what the builtin `dir()` will say about names in your module.

---

What `sh` does is more sophisticated, as they want to support versions below 3.7: Modifying `sys.modules` and replacing the module with a special object that pretends to be a module.

Comment: So I'm assuming this goes in a class called at module startup...?

Comment: This goes directly into the module, there's no need for classes. My code example is literally all you need in a file in order to be able to import `t` from it.

Comment: Thank you! Quick question, however: I modified it to simply print the name when called; the result is `__path__ <newline> t <newline> t` (I can't quite put newlines here). How can I get rid of the `__path__` and the extra `t`?

Comment: Python itself looks for a `__path__` inside every module to figure out of it's a package, you'll have to just ignore it (something like `if name == "__path__": raise AttributeError`). The fact that `t` is imported twice I also noticed, seems to be an artifact of the import mechanics. The [Python docs on that](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) are quite extensive.

Comment: Hmm... I will attempt to figure it out myself, then; thank you kindly for the help!

Comment: `if name == "__path__": raise AttributeError` removes both the `__path__` and duplication error! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @L3viathan pointed out, this is easy [starting with Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/): just define a `__getattr__` function in your special module. So, for example, you could create an "echo" module (just returns the name of the object you requested) like this:

`echo.py` (Python >=3.7)

```
def __getattr__(name):
    return name
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
from echo import x
print(repr(x))
# 'x'
```

On earlier versions of Python, you have to subclass the module, as hinted in [PEP-562](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/). This also works in Python 3.7.

`echo.py` (Python >=2)

```
import sys, types

class EchoModule(types.ModuleType):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return name

sys.modules[__name__] = EchoModule(__name__)
```

You would use this the same way as the 3.7 version: `from echo import something`.

**Update**

For some reason Python tries to retrieve the attribute twice for each `from echo import <x>` call. It also calls `__getattr__('__path__')` when the module is loaded. You can avoid side effects in these cases with the following code:

`echo.py` (only define attributes once)

```
import sys, types

class EchoModule(types.ModuleType):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # don't define __path__ attribute
        if name == '__path__':
            raise AttributeError
        print("importing {}".format(name))
        # create the attribute in case it's required again
        setattr(self, name, name)
        # return the new attribute
        return getattr(self, name)

sys.modules[__name__] = EchoModule(__name__)
```

This code creates an attribute in the `echo` module each time a previously unused attribute is imported (sort of like [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)). Then, if Python tries to import that same attribute again later, it will pull it directly from the module instead of calling `__getattr__` (this is [normal behavior](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) for object attributes).

There is also some code here to avoid setting a spurious `__path__` attribute; this also avoids running your code when `__path__` is requested. Note that this may actually be the most important part; when I tested, just raising `AttributeError` for `__path__` was enough to prevent the double-access to the named attribute.

Comment: Well it removes the duplication issue; thank you for that! Would you happen to know if I can use the `name` in the same way for other parts of the module, as in passing `name` around in a variable? Essentially use the string representation somewhere else?

Comment: You should be able to store the name (or something based on it) as an attribute of `self` and access it from other methods of `EchoClass` later. You might also be able to store it in a global variable in the original `echo.py`. Can you give a more concrete example of what you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to get only the name of the `from` import, for example, if I was attempting `from module import t`, I'd want to only get `t` as a string; however, at the moment, if I put it in self, or print it, it prints out `__path__ <newline> t <newline> t` (I can't quite put newlines here). Only when I use your method of returning `name` can I get a single string, i.e. only `t`. So essentially, is there a way to get the single string and put it into `self` without returning it first?

Comment: Sure, in `__getattr__`, you could just do something like `self.last_import = name`. Then you can retrieve the name by accessing `self.last_import` (within `EchoModule`) or `echo.last_import` (from outside). But what would you want to do next? Can you write some pseudocode showing what you're hoping to achieve?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still duplicates, i.e. `__path__ <newline> t <newline> t` whenever I put it in a variable; I need to get rid of the `__path__` and the extra `t`. That way, as per the question, I can import, for example, a shell program from the `shell` path, etc.

Comment: I added a new version that should avoid these side effects. You may be able to adapt this to do what you need.

Comment: `if name == "__path__": raise AttributeError` removes both the `__path__` and duplication error! Thank you!